# How do I replace lost plastic tiles for Scrabble?

Tags: scrabble

Two of the letter tiles from my Hungarian language Scrabble set are lost.  These are bright gray plastic tiles with the letters etched and painted on them.  Is there a way I can obtain replacement for just those tiles?

Obviously I'm interested only if replacement is significantly cheaper than buying a complete new set.

Answer (score 2):

Try emailing Hasbro.  It is a bit hard to find where to contact customer support.  This should work:

https://hasbro-new.custhelp.com/app/ask